# Why does my class suddenly have a 'designer'?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I just finished adding and removing different database models (I was trying to figure out which one I should be using for this project) then after playing around for a while I noticed one of my classes's icon changed from what is shows beside my Calculations.cs class in the first image to the Balance.cs icon.

[image]

The Balance.cs now has this Designer component so when I double click on it I see my second screen shot. This seems to be allowing me to add components from the toolbox to my class. There are actually two classes within my Balance.cs. This Designer thing is only affecting/interacting with one of them (it inherits from SerialPort).

[image]

I don't really know what changed or what I did to make this happen and ctrl+z is not being my friend here. How do I change Balance.cs back to a regular class with no designer component?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If any of the classes in a source file inherit - either directly or indirectly - from `System.ComponentModel.Component` (such as `SerialPort`), Visual Studio will provide design-time support to you. This is sometimes unwanted behaviour, and you can safely ignore it in most cases.

If it really bothers you, you can decorate your class with the `[DesignerCategory]` attribute (set the category to an empty string).

Comment: I'd opened and closed the project and built it several times and it didn't change until now. Do you know why that would be?  What's the syntax for the DesignerCategory? Do I put `[DesignerCategory("")]` above my class which inherits from SerialPort?

Comment: Correct, that's the syntax. You may need to add a `using System.ComponentModel;` to the top of your source file if it's not already there. Visual Studio usually waits until you compile the the project successfully before it starts offering designer functionality.